# Thymeleaf th:field and th:value give me different result

Tags: boolean, thymeleaf

Even if the server returns "false" value for a certain parameter, on html it becomes "true" for some reason when I use "th:field". "th:value" gives me "false" as expected.

code

```
<input th:field="*{attachedFilelist__${fileType}__[__${stat.index}__].deletedFlag}">
<input th:value="*{attachedFilelist__${fileType}__[__${stat.index}__].deletedFlag}">
```

I put this code for debug purpose and html is as shown below.

[image]

Moreover, this happens only when I delete certain file on the screen before it is redirected to the same page with some validation error. So I'm guessing it might have something to do with cache or something but for now I have no clue.

Hope my question makes sense and someone can give me some information.
Any info/advice will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do only debugging then use something like `<p th:text="${object}*>`.
Let me know if this work for you or not.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I changed it to
`<p th:text="*{attachedFilelist__${fileType}__[__${stat.index}__]}">`
and it gave me this:
com.domain.dto.entity.FileManagement@696e5a44

Comment: override `toString()` method. You will be able to see the object.

Comment: Could you elaborate the comment above? How do I override the method?